# Trademarking a product that contains a library licensed under Apache 2.0

Tags: licensing, software, open-source-software

I have a web application that makes use of the well known Twitter Bootstrap library which is released under Apache License 2.0 with Creative Commons CC-BY 3.0.

Can I trademark this application?

Note: I am trying to make sense of the Trademark notice under the Forbidden section on http://choosealicense.com/licenses/apache-2.0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the *libraries* trademarks, but that does not stop you from using your own. For example, you cannot use the name *Twitter Bootstrap* to endorse, promote or use as the name of your project.

Comment: RE:"You cannot use the libraries trademarks"  so I couldn't say "MyProduct™ -  a Twitter Bootstrap™ based awesomeness", but I can go ahead and Trademark the product called MyProduct

Comment: @dwkd Pretty much :)